# Syntax error using "with fields" in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm working through Real World OCaml and I'm getting a syntax error on the following bit of code:

```
`# module Logon = struct
    type t =
      { session_id: string;
        time: Time.t;
        user: string;
        credentials: string;
      }
    with fields
  end;;
```

On running, Utop underlines the word "with" and throws a syntax error. I've tried similar, more simple examples on my own and get the same error.  Any thoughts on what's going on?

EDIT: Omitted "}" added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ocaml 4.01.0 :
In utop : `#require "fieldslib.syntax";;` is solving the issue. (... do not forget to run  `opam install fieldslib`).

For recent ocaml :
(got some hints [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ocaml-core/g9UfzyQ0hL8) ).

> opam install ppx_jane fieldslib

```
#require  "ppx_jane";;
#require "fieldslib";; 
module Logon = struct
    type t =
      { session_id: string;
        time: Time.t;
        user: string;
        credentials: string;
      }
    [@@deriving fields]
  end;;
```

Comment: No dice for me ... on `#require "fieldslib.syntax";;` I get "no such package: fieldslib.syntax".  However, opam insists that fieldslib is already installed (on `opam install fieldslib`) and also up-to-date (on `opam upgrade fieldslib`).  Also, within utop `#require fieldslib";;` does not fix the problem.

Comment: it works with ocaml 4.01.0, but not with 4.02.3 where I cannot get the fieldslib.syntax (same issue like  you @John Binder).

Comment: What is @@deriving? How should I find out more about this syntax?

Answer (score 1):

For me I needed to add this, in utop:

```
#require "ppx_fields_conv";;
```